# Stop Ubuntu from trying to load a GUI

Tags: boot, command-line, server, gui

So I have a computer running Ubuntu Server 12.04, and one operation I did needed a GUI (the application was graphical) so, being a noob, I ran:

```
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
```

This worked great and allowed me to have a GUI for the thing I needed to do, but now I can't get rid of it! In hindsight I should have just ran:

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4
```

Which would allow me to `startx` into a GUI. Anyways, I've removed xubuntu-desktop and purged all related things, but when I start up the computer instead of booting tot he CLI like a normal linux server, it attempts to load up a bunch of GUI related things including LightDM and then hangs. How can I revert it to its original server ways?

Answer (score 2):

You need to re-configure grub so that it boots in text mode. Don't worry it's easy peasy.

## Steps:

Step #1

In terminal type

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Step #2

change line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text"
```

Step #3

In terminal type

```
sudo update-grub
```

## Notes:

Note #1

This doesn't remove any desktop environments it just makes Ubuntu boot in terminal mode instead.

Note #2

You absolutely can use Xubuntu-desktop rather than xfce4, just bear in mind that sometimes when you install desktop environments they will list a desktop manager (aka login screen) as a dependency. The result is that the computer will start booting in gui mode unless you reconfigure it not to.

## Sources:

http://postbin.per.red/pages/article23/page.php